# Wildcard + SQL Parameter in Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, wildcard

I created a procedure in order to search for a product, but I got a problem, as I would like to use wildcards with a param (nam) , but I don't get them to work.

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE NAME LIKE NAM + '%'

SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE NAME LIKE '%'+ NAM + '%'
```

...

Thank you so much.

Comment: Parameters generally start with a the `@` symbol, which I don't see in your select statements.  Did you mean to use `SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE NAME LIKE @NAM + '%'`?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: that is not correct for every DBMS. Guess you`re assuming SQL Server or similar, me too ;).

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Yes, that's actually what I really would like to do. EDIT Fast responses! PHPMyAdmin MySQL v5.6.12

Comment: @timo.rieber - my brain told me that there was a [sql-server] tag here, but that apparently is not the case ;)

Comment: Can you share the full code of your procedure?